# I have written C# code for login check and user type check. Logic seems to be correct but why is the output not correct?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written C# code for login check and user type check. Logic seems to be correct but why is the output not correct?

i did some edits here.
please check this now.

No redirection is taking place
No redirection is taking place
No redirection is taking place

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Bidders_Joint
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BiddersJoint"].ToString();
            string type;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Type from TABLE_USER where User_ID = @userid AND Password=@password", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", txtUserid.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text.ToString());
            try
            {
                con.Open();//cmd.Connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        type = dr["Type"].ToString();
                        if (type == "admin")
                        {
                            Response.Redirect("administrator.aspx");
                            Response.End();
                        }
                        else if (type == "general")
                        {
                            Response.Redirect("userspage.aspx");
                            Response.End();
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        lblMessage.Text = "wrong userid or password";
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close(); //cmd.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please hash your passwords.

Comment: What @Igor said. And there are a few other things you might want to consider to have "cleaner" code. First and foremost, it seems like you're storing the password in the database in plain text. That's very bad! Please read up on "hashing" and "salting" passwords. There is a lot here on SO. Then you store the password in a variable, that is visible for the whole class. That shouldn't be necessary. Declare it as close as possible to the place where you work with it. In this case, just before the `while`. Speaking of that, why use a `while`? do you expect >1 results? Just use `if (dr.Read())`.

Comment: And what should happen if `dr.Read()` fails? Also, you're mixing two things, checking the password and the type. Check (only) the password first. If it doesn't match, write the "wrong userid ..." message and return. And after you know the password must have matched, have a switch on the `type` to know which site to redirect to.

Comment: I Don't know about your database structure, but I just notice you are finding user based on "UserID", most developer make that Autoincrement Numeric id, and not a "username" check your DB, if you have different username field?

Answer (score 2):

Connect the first and second `if`s with `else`:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
      password = dr["Password"].ToString();
      type = dr["Type"].ToString();
      if ((password == txtPassword.Text.ToString()) && (type == "admin"))
      {
         Response.Redirect("administrator.aspx");
      }
      else if ((password==txtPassword.Text.ToString()) && (type=="general"))
      {
         Response.Redirect("userspage.aspx");
      }
}

lblMessage.Text = "wrong userid or password";
```

**Update:**

```
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                        type = dr["Type"].ToString();
                        if (type == "admin")
                        {
                            Response.Redirect("administrator.aspx");
                            Response.End();
                        }
                        else if (type == "general")
                        {
                            Response.Redirect("userspage.aspx");
                            Response.End();
                        }
                }
                lblMessage.Text = "wrong userid or password";
```

Comment: and use Response.End() After each redirect always, this ensure the code after Redirect doesn't get executed, which may be is harmful in few cases.

Comment: are they not connected in my code? I think mine ifs blocks are also the same as you shown here.

Comment: @SumitGupta - this is default behaviour for `Response.Redirect` with one parameter

Comment: please tell me why I am always getting wrong userid or password.:(

Comment: @Igor, I used the else if, but still the problem is persisting

Comment: You might want to separate checking `password` and `type`. Try `if (password != txtPassword.Text.ToString()) { lblMessage.Text = "wrong userid or password"; return; }` first (set a breakpoint here and check if you really get the right password and if it really matches the one from the db you got). Notice the `!=`. After that you know the password matched. Now you can switch over the type and redirect to the corresponding page.

Comment: @anshulpui - Are `USER_ID` values in `TABLE_USER` unique? Move the checking code inside your `while` loop - see my edited answer.

Comment: @all: I changed my entire code as below, and even now nothing is happening. I am also not getting wrong userid or password message.

Comment: @anshulpui - and how sure are you that the text entered into the textbox and the one stored in the db (which is still a very bad idea!) are the same?

Comment: @anshulpui - see my update. you need to practice to mentally (or on paper) execute your own code.

Comment: @Corak: I am entering the same details in text boxes as it is in table  of my database.